# How to return the number of sets for each date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am running a query that returns:

```
Date       Set   Data
2021-07-02  1      A
2021-07-02  2      B
2021-07-02  3      C
2021-08-15  1      D
2021-10-27  1      E
2021-10-27  2      F
```

I need to also return the number of Sets for each date:

```
Date       Set   Data NoSets
2021-07-02  1      A     3
2021-07-02  2      B     3
2021-07-02  3      C     3
2021-08-15  1      D     1
2021-10-27  1      E     2
2021-10-27  2      F     2

SELECT csm_pat_exe_date.pedate_id, csm_patient_exercise.pat_exe_id,  
                 csm_exercise_details.ede_id, csm_exercise.exe_id, 
ses_pat_id, ses_pat_note, ses_pat_body_weight, ses_pat_blood_pressure, ses_pat_blood_glucose_level,
exe_name, ede_order, ede_type,  
                 ede_unit, weekofyear(csm_pat_exe_date.pedate_date) AS weekNumber, csm_pat_exe_date.pedate_date, peds_id, peds_set, peds_result, pedate_note, t2.noSets  
                 FROM csm_session_patient, csm_session, csm_exercise, csm_patient_exercise, csm_exercise_details,  
                     csm_pat_exe_date_set, csm_pat_exe_date 
INNER JOIN ( 
                     SELECT pedate_date, COUNT(*) as noSets 
                         FROM csm_patient_exercise, csm_pat_exe_date
                    WHERE  csm_patient_exercise.pat_id = '1'
                          AND csm_patient_exercise.pat_exe_id = csm_pat_exe_date.pat_exe_id
                     GROUP BY pedate_date 
                     ) t2 ON csm_pat_exe_date.pedate_date = t2.pedate_date
 
                 WHERE csm_session_patient.pat_id= '1'
AND csm_session_patient.ses_id = csm_session.ses_id 
                     AND csm_session.ses_date = csm_pat_exe_date.pedate_date
AND exe_archived IS NULL  
                     AND csm_exercise.exe_id = csm_patient_exercise.exe_id   
                     AND csm_patient_exercise.pat_exe_id = '1'   
                     AND csm_patient_exercise.exe_id = csm_patient_exercise.pat_exe_id  
                     AND csm_patient_exercise.pat_exe_id = csm_pat_exe_date.pat_exe_id 
AND csm_pat_exe_date.pedate_date >= '2021-06-01'  
                     AND csm_pat_exe_date.pedate_date <= '2021-09-24'  
                     AND csm_pat_exe_date.pedate_id = csm_pat_exe_date_set.pedate_id 
 
                     AND csm_pat_exe_date_set.ede_id = csm_exercise_details.ede_id  
                 ORDER BY csm_pat_exe_date.pedate_date, peds_set, ede_order;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may add the count window function to your select clause eg

**Mysql 8+**

```sql
    SELECT
        `Date`,
        `Set`,
        `Data`,
        `NoSets`,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Date) as NoSets
    FROM
      ...include the rest of your query here
```

**Older Mysql Versions**
You may use variables or aggregates to achieve your count

**Schema (MySQL v5.5)**

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  `Date` DATETIME,
  `Set` INTEGER,
  `Data` VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO my_table
  (`Date`, `Set`, `Data`)
VALUES
  ('2021-07-02', '1', 'A'),
  ('2021-07-02', '2', 'B'),
  ('2021-07-02', '3', 'C'),
  ('2021-08-15', '1', 'D'),
  ('2021-10-27', '1', 'E'),
  ('2021-10-27', '2', 'F');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT
    `Date`,
    `Set`,
    `Data`,
    `NoSets`
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*, 
        @maxcnt:=IF(@prevdate2=`DATE`,IF(@maxcnt>cnt,@maxcnt,cnt),cnt) as NoSets,
        @prevdate2:=`Date`
    FROM (
        SELECT
            @cnt:=IF(@prevdate1=`DATE`,@cnt+1,1) as cnt,
            @prevdate1:=`Date`,
            m.*
        FROM 
            my_table m
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @cnt:=0,@prevdate1:=NULL) vars
        ORDER BY `Date`
    ) t 
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @maxcnt:=0,@prevdate2:=NULL) vars
    ORDER BY `Date`,cnt DESC
) t2;
```

| Date | Set | Data | NoSets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-02 00:00:00 | 3 | C | 3 |
| 2021-07-02 00:00:00 | 2 | B | 3 |
| 2021-07-02 00:00:00 | 1 | A | 3 |
| 2021-08-15 00:00:00 | 1 | D | 1 |
| 2021-10-27 00:00:00 | 2 | F | 2 |
| 2021-10-27 00:00:00 | 1 | E | 2 |

---

**Query #2**

```
SELECT
    t1.`Date`,
    t1.`Set`,
    t1.`Data`,
    t2.`NoSets`
FROM
    my_table t1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT `Date`, COUNT(*) as NoSets
    FROM my_table
    GROUP BY `Date`
) t2 ON t1.`Date`=t2.`Date`;
```

| Date | Set | Data | NoSets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-02 00:00:00 | 1 | A | 3 |
| 2021-07-02 00:00:00 | 2 | B | 3 |
| 2021-07-02 00:00:00 | 3 | C | 3 |
| 2021-08-15 00:00:00 | 1 | D | 1 |
| 2021-10-27 00:00:00 | 1 | E | 2 |
| 2021-10-27 00:00:00 | 2 | F | 2 |

---

or

```sql
SELECT
    t1.`Date`,
    t1.`Set`,
    t1.`Data`,
    (
      SELECT COUNT(*) FROM my_table t2 WHERE t2.Date=t1.Date
    ) as `NoSets`
FROM
    my_table t1
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mnh78x8GVATsA1KHeWwqxg/2)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Yep, `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Date)` is the key part of the solution. In this time and age I would stick with MySQL 8.x, and add solutions for older versions only when specifically asked. +1

Comment: Thank you @ggordon. I have edited the question to include the final code.